# Port Scanner 3.5 Python Print Issue After Going Through set range

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

```
import socket
import sys
from datetime import datetime

#Ask the user for input, the form of a remote host entire in the IP address of the target machine
remoteServer =input ("Enter a remote host to scan:")
remoteServerIP =socket.gethostbyname(remoteServer)

#Print a block of text with information on which host we are about to scan.
#While scanning display a message so the user knows the program is working and isn't frozen
print ("_"*60)
print ("Please wait, currently scanning remote host", remoteServerIP)
print ("_"*60)

#Show/check the time scan started
t1 = datetime.now()

#range function to specify ports, this case I have set the pogram to go through ports 1 to 150
# port in range works like so
try:
     for port in range (1, 150):
         sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
         result = sock.connect_ex((remoteServerIP, port))
         if result == 0:
            print ("Port {}:     Open".format(port))
         sock.close()

# Press Ctrl C to leave the application
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("You pressed Ctrl+C")
    sys.exit()

except socket.gaierror:
    print ('Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting')
    sys.exit()

except socket.error:
    print ("Couldn't connect to server")
    sys.exit()

# Checking the time again
t2 = datetime.now()

# Calculates the difference of time, to see how long it took to run the script
total =  t2 - t1

# Printing the information to screen
print ('Scanning Completed in: ', total)
```

My boss has told me to start learning about Metasploitable2 and Kali Linux  as such I have attempted to create a port scanner it seems to work fine for most of the part however. after if has finished scanning the ports within it's set range it close completely rather then print ('Scanning Completed in: ', total) with listed findings. What have I done wrong here? And I 'm well aware this is script slow I'm going to attempt to make it multithreaded later on.

Comment: The script works for me (on MacOSX, using Python 3.5.2), the "scanning completed in ..." line shows fine.  So the problem may be with your setup rather than with the script?

Comment: so my machine or the actuall python progam itself that's what you're thinking?